# can not update 12.10 to 13.04

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, 13.04, update-manager

Trying to get to 14 version by updating 12.40 to 13.04 but get failed fetch error. Have tried upgrade through Software updater and get all the way through to the update prompt "you should update to 13.04" I click update get the 'release notes' window and select 'upgrade' and than i get the 'Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.' have tried numerous things to no avail.

Comment: Dont Do it @Gary Scheller,  do sudo do-release-upgrade  and get the latest stable.

Comment: tried this and it returned -- WARNING:root:file 'raring.tar.gz.gpg' missing
Failed to fetch

Comment: tried the software updater and it returns --

Comment: tried the software updater, no luck. Tried changing the file "/var/lib/update-manager/meta-release" to replace "archive.ubuntu.com" to "old-releases.ubuntu.com" - it aborted after a while. Have tried the 'sudo do-release-upgrade'  and it returns 'Error during update 
A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of 
network problem, please check your network connection and retry.' I have tried letting Software Sources 'find the best server' returns 'none available'.  Feel I am overlooking something really inane but can't solve it.

Answer (score -1):

Upgrading to 13.04 or 13.10 is not required. You can directly upgrade to 14.04.

> do-release-upgrade

You might have to add SUDO depending on your privilege.